# Is there a function to turn string into actual operation?

Tags: python, boolean

I'm looking for a function to turn string into operation:

For example:

```
list = ["duck", "rubber", "rubberduck", "duckrubber"]
statement = "duck AND rubber OR rubberduck"

# then i want to turn statement into operation, such that:

for i in list:
    if i.is_in(statement): # or is_in(i, statement) 
        print(i)
```

but I can't figure out how to make "is_in()" function as I think there's virtually no way to turn string into python operation. Any idea to tackle this?

EDIT: Apologize for the unclear question, the answer to this question is using expr from python standard library and then structure the input so that we can use re.sub() to then put "in "

Comment: Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  From what little problem description you gave, it seems that you simply want the `in` operator.  However, if there were the case, you'd already know it from your learning materials and your browser search before posting.

Comment: it's not in operator because then I have to type the actual operation. In actuality I can just write if ("duck" in I and "rubber" in I) or ("rubberduck" in i), but I have to type them manually, I want to process user input query as in statement and automatically process them into python code

Comment: What is ``z`` ?

Comment: I just edited, my bad, it's list not z

Comment: (1) Again, please repeat the applicable parts of the intro tour.  Information critical to the question must be edited into the question, not left in comments.  (2) Your comment is inconsistent; you're trying to combine `statement` with syntactic knowledge of Boolean precedence and natural-language assumptions about a semantic distributive property.  This is not turning a string into an **operation**.  The effect you describe requires application-specific rules coded into some form of a parser; there is no built-in Python capability to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that checks if a string is in another by the count method of strings

```
list = ["duck", "rubber", "rubberduck", "duckrubber"]
statement = "duck AND rubber OR rubberduck"

def is_in(i, statement):
    return statement.lower().count(i) > 0

for i in list:
    if is_in(i, statement):
        print(i)
```

will print

```
duck
rubber
rubberduck
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

for check full string is in list

```
# then i want to turn statement into operation, such that:

if  statement in list:
   print(statement)
else :
   print('no')
```

for check words in list

```
x=statement.split(' ')
for x in list:
   print(x)
```

Comment: Neither of these addresses OPs given problem.  Run your code and look at the results.